# How to show a popup using an AngularJS custom directive

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-ui-tooltip

I want to show a popup using directives

HTML Code:

```
<td hover-popup>Hi there</td>
```

hover-popup is my directive.

I have tried following

```
link: function (scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
    elm.attr('tooltip', 'abc');
    $compile(elm)($rootScope);
}
```

and

```
link: function (scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
    el.attr('tooltip', 'abc');
    var fn = $compile(el);
        return function(scope){
            fn(scope);
    }
}
```

On hovering "Hi there", I want popup to show.
Above two codes are not working.
Thanks

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Consider using the [uib-tooltip](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tooltip) directive from the [AngularUI Team](https://angular-ui.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

ng-transclude can do the trick

```
angular.module('transcludeExample', [])
 .directive('pane', function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { title:'@' },
        template: '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
                    '<div ng-if="showTooltip" style="background-color: gray">tooltip</div>' +
                    '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
                  '</div>',
        link: function(scope, element) {
          element.bind('mouseenter', function(e) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              scope.showTooltip = true;  
            })
          });
          element.bind('mouseleave', function(e) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              scope.showTooltip = false;  
            })
          });

        },
      };
  });
```

[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/guyogev/pen/veargr?editors=1010#0)

Comment: Hi, thanks but I don't want a extra div, I want to insert tooltip in same div.

Comment: You'll need 3 "boxes", one for the element (<td>  at your example), one for the tooltip (div/span... whatever), and a wrapper for them both.

what you call what doesn't really matter